# Apple Ipod and C#

Tags: c#, .net, ipod

What would be the best way to read ipod songs with C#. I am thinking of doing a interface to the ipod as a test :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This question came up in a google search, but the first reasonable answer I found took a while longer:

[SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/) has a .Net (2.0) library for iPod access, and apparently supports all the latest iPods and iPhones (I have not personally tested it):

http://www.getsharepod.com/fordevelopers/

It's free for non-commercial use, and seems pretty cheap for licensed use ($99 at this time)

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I am now trying SharePod player on Win8 x64. I have extracted iTunes64 installer with 7zip and installed Apple Application Support and Mobile Device Support. Then I can play music directly from iPod Classic with SharePod's music player. No need to install full iTunes (not sure about iPhone and iPod Touch).

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vauge so I shall answer based upon the ways I can see of interpretting it.

I can't speak about the current generation (Touch) devices because they have changed things but I do know that prior to this the songs  were stored within the iPod_Control directory. These files are name-magled so in order to read information such as the track and artist name one must extreact it from the udata atom of the sound file itself.

iTunes and the iPod use MPEG-4 AAC audio for sound files so playing them involves extracting this data from the data atom of the sound file and passing it to an a capable renderer such as iTunes or QuckTime which are accessible from managed code via COM.

It is possible to render MP4-AAC without quicktime or itunes using 3rd party libraries and codecs but I have not explored this.

Apple recently stopped using DRM in the iTunes store however, if using third party audio libraries you might have problems rendering audio files which are encrypted in this manner

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search gave me:

- http://www.kbcafe.com/juice/?guid=20050507072047
- http://projects.gnome.org/hipo/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I miss a theme but You can try [Here](http://www.getsharepod.com/)