# How can I use iTunesLib in unattended mode?

Tags: c#, itunes, com-interop, itunes-sdk

I'm making a little app to automate my iPod update. My purpose is sync my iTunes library with my actual one and reencode songs in a lower quality for the iPod.

I use the Interop "iTunesLib" from iTunes.exe and I'm working on C#.

My program works pretty well but I have a big issue with iTunes. If a modal box is opened by iTunes during the process (could be "error while importing song", or just even "a new update is available" at iTunes startup...), then my app is completely stuck and must wait for the user to close the popup.

This is annoying because I expected to run my app at night and the process of reimporting/reencoding takes a while.

Is there any way to either tell iTunes to not pop any message, or to ask it to close an already opened one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after having this question open for more than a year, the correct answers seems to be: **I can't**

However there are several [alternative libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901319/apple-ipod-and-c-sharp) that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try calling the IiTunes.VisualsEnabled method passing in `FALSE`.

From the iTunes COM SDK:

```
HRESULT IiTunes::VisualsEnabled  (  [in] VARIANT_BOOL  shouldEnable   )   

   Set whether visuals should be displayed. 


Parameters:
 shouldEnable  True if visuals should be displayed. 

Return values:
 S_OK  The operation was successful.  
 E_ACCESSDENIED  Visuals cannot be enabled or disabled. For example, this can happen if the iTunes Store is currently being viewed.  
 E_FAIL  An unexpected error occurred.
```

Comment: The name might be ambiguous, but this property (it's a property in C#, not a method) just turns on or off the visual effect displayed when playing a song. When I call the constructor of `iTunesAppClass`, the iTunes process is spawned and the UI becomes visible before the constructor returns. If there is a solution to my problem, it would be by doing something before calling the constructor. But there is no provided static method I can call anyway, everything is a member of `iTunesAppClass`. the I still have no solution yet.

Comment: Ok.  You can submit a feature request here: https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/